# How to set a breakpoint to the corresponding method when a button is clicked?

Tags: ios, xcode, breakpoints

I'm checking out an open-source iOS project. I want to get the breakpoints to the corresponding method is invoked when I click a button IN THE SIMULATOR. How can I do that in XCode?

There are times when button are added in programmatically and one cannot search for details in the storyboard.

**Edit**: I know how to add a breakpoints in general.

Comment: Do you want to add the breakpoint to action of button click right?

Comment: Yes. But the breakpoint should go to the corresponding method of the button automatically when I click it in the simulator

Comment: I think you are adding button programmatically if that the case, then add the breakpoint to the method which you are adding as selector to that button. If that is not the case, then explain your question in brief, so that will help you

Comment: I've simulated an open-source project (which's not written by me). There are various image buttons in it. I want to know which method will be called when I click a button.

Had the buttons have some text, I've would searched for the string names but they being images it's being very tough to figure out which method is called under-the-hood!

Comment: Find the place where the buttons are created/added to the UI. There it is likely also stated which method to call (with the addTarget:action:forControlEvents: method)

Answer (score 0):

Click on left panel marked in image and one blue make will appear on that location when **compiler** will come on that line it will stop there and will show all the values of objects and variables.

[image: Click on left panel marked in image]